# Inner Join on Multiple Tables with Table Format

Tags: sql-server

These are related tables and foreign key is guaranteed to exists. the tables are dynamic but they all starts with name and is appended with a creation number.

So I can have tables like data1 up to data7, data1 up to data51

And while I can format my query in C#. I just feel there is a much better way than adding an Inner Join per table, you may imagine this gets ugly after 10 tables.

All tables have different columns.

```
SELECT *
FROM data1 as t1
INNER JOIN data2 as t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
INNER JOIN data3 as t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
```

Comment: I am lost here, what is the question? A better way to replace inner join?

Comment: @jyao yes. I was hoping there's a simpler way, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do the tables have the same columns, or do they all have different columns?

Comment: LEFT JOIN should be best way, did you tried already?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I've edited my question and yes they are different.

Comment: @Crismogram, will a `VIEW `help in this scenario but I think your query changes every time you create a new one ie, you append the new table to this query?